# Array element to object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a question on how to get the elements of an Array from another array's element.  I can't get scores from the teams score array.  I can see that the nth character of the name is returned.

```
 function runData() {
    var Teams = ["bears", "pats", "qbs"];

    var bears = [34, 45, 23];
    var pats = [24, 33, 41];
    var qbs = [33, 41, 28];

    for (t = 0; t < Teams.length; t++) {
        var teamToGet = Teams[t];
        getScore();
        var para = document.createElement("p");
        pageOut = teamToGet; para.innerHTML = pageOut;
        document.getElementById("p1").appendChild(para);
    }

    function getScore() {
        var score = teamToGet[t];
        teamToGet += "-" + score;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the code formatting was typo'd, could you take a look?

Comment: If you're trying to access a variable by name, you shouldn't. Instead have an object `scores = {"bears": [34,45,23], ...};` and then access `scores[teamToGet]`.

Comment: Inside your `getScore()` method, how is `t` recognized as defined? It doesn't exist inside that closure scope. You need to pass in the variable through a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just because you're populating your teams array with strings instead of the arrays of the other teams.

Now when you loop through teams, you'll get an object with the team name and scores array, not just a string of the team name.

```
function runData() {

    var bears = { name : "bears", scores : [ 34, 45, 23 ] };
    var pats  = { name : "pats", scores : [ 1, 2, 3 ] };
    var qbs   = { name : "qbs", scores : [ 33, 41, 28 ] };

    var Teams = [ bears, pats, qbs ]; 

    for( var t = 0; t < Teams.length; t++ ) {
        var teamToGet = Teams[t]; // will be an object
        var score     = getScore( teamToGet );
        var para      = document.createElement( "p" );
        // not sure what you're doing here
        // pageOut = para.innerHTML = pageOut;
        // document.getElementById( "p1" ).appendChild( para );
    }

    function getScore( team ) {
        // not exactly sure what you're doing here.
        // I'll just return the first score.
        return team.name += "-" + team.scores[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a word @KDOT that your reformat, while I like it, doesn't meet a lot of standard style guides. I tend to use a lot more spaces than most style guides, more similar to how you do it, but the overall standard I've seen at places like Google, Bloomberg, Reuters, etc. is cuddle just about everything, { never : this } {always : this} and so on.

Comment: I merely indented it for SO formatting, not the code. I only added the code format where best suited. The intention was the answer format since you had `}` and `function runData()` hanging outside the code space.